# Are there any known methods to compute series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^k \big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n2^{k+1}+(2k+1))^3}\big)$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I would like to ask if there are any known methods  to compute series like this one ?
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^k \bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n2^{k+1}+(2k+1))^3}\bigg)$$
And their names so i can look for them if they exist.
I never studied double sums before that's why i am asking, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "study" ?

Comment: See if it converges or not, and calculate it if possible !

Comment: These are quite different tasks, to the point of being nearly unrelated, like _"take a photo of Mt. Everest"_ and _"climb Mt. Everest"_. The inner series obviously does converge; the rest is not that easy.

Comment: Actually i already know that it converges, now i just need to know ther are any methods known to compute this kind of sums, so do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form solution or numerical?

Comment: i am not looking for a solution, i am looking for lessons, methods name or books that could help me learn how to compute double series like this one !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 2^k \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n2^{k+1}+2k+1)^3} =\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{(2k+1)^3} - \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2^{2k+3}}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n+\frac{2k+1}{2^{k+1}})^3}\right)$

and

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n+a)^3}=\frac{1}{8}\left(\zeta(3,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{2})-\zeta(3,1+\frac{a}{2})\right)\,$ . $\hspace{1cm}$ (see: *Hurwitz zeta function*)

It follows

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2k+3}}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n+\frac{2k+1}{2^{k+1}})^3}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2k+6}}\left(\zeta(3,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2k+1}{2^{k+2}})-\zeta(3,1+\frac{2k+1}{2^{k+2}})\right)$

$\hspace{5.5cm}\approx 0.05957499...$

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{(2k+1)^3}$ is divergent because $\displaystyle\left(\frac{2^k}{(2k+1)^3}\right)_k$ is *not* a null sequence and

$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2^{2k+3}}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n+\frac{2k+1}{2^{k+1}})^3}\right)$ is convergent therefore the initial series is divergent.

Comment: @HptunjyPrjkeizg : Thanks for the bounty! I hope I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to get an other form for the $\zeta (3)$.
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\space =\space \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^3}\space + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^3}$$
Or:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\space - \frac{1}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3} \space = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^3}$$
$$\frac{7}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\space = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^3} \tag{1}$$
$$\frac{7}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\space = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^3}\space + \space 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4n+3)^3} \tag{2}$$
What i'm trying to do is to express it using a sum of alternate sums.

$$\frac{7}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\space = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)^3}\space + \space 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(4n+3)^3}\space +\space 4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(8n+7)^3}\space + \space ... \space +\space 2^k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2^{k+1}n+(2^{k+1}-1))^3}$$
Which is a double sum : 
$$\frac{7}{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}\space = \space \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2^{k+1}n+(2^{k+1}-1))^3}$$
that is actually what $\zeta(3)$ is equal to, i typed it wrong in the question <. < and maybe that is why it's divegent !

Comment: @user90369 here's the proof of the double sum expression for $\zeta(3)$

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 2^k \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2^{k+1}(n+1)-1)^3}=$ 
$\displaystyle =\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 2^k \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2^{k+1}(n+1)-1)^3} - 2\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty 2^k \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2^{k+1}(2n+2)-1)^3}  $
$\displaystyle =\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{(2^{k+1}(n+1)-1)^3} - \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^{k+1}}{(2^{k+2}(n+1)-1)^3} $
$\displaystyle =\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^0}{(2^1(n+1)-1)^3}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{(2n+1)^3}$

Comment: @user90369 if the series is not ocnvergent even when we add the N+1 term, then can you tell me where is the mistake i made ? when i tryed to go from $\zeta(3)$ to this ?

Comment: What you've calculated *in your own answer* is *correct*. I *only* show the reverse way in my comment. --- For the other series (the series at the beginning in your question) I have shown you in my answer (first line), what the problem is: The first part (n=0) of this series is $\sum\limits_{k\geq 0}\frac{2^k}{(2k+1)^3}$, which is divergent. --- And please: Don't confuse $\,\frac{(-1)^n}{(2^{k+1}n+2^{k+1}-1)^3}\,$ with $\,\frac{(-1)^n}{(2^{k+1}n+2k+1)^3}\,$, they make a big difference here .

Comment: omg yes i just saw it, it's the first series, thx alot for everything,  !

Comment: You are welcome. :-)